# Background image using the background-image property not appearing so not able to get the desired display

Tags: html, css

I am new to html/css and I do not understand why my background image is not showing up over the button in the search box on the right. I want to display an image of magnifying glass over the right button in the search box?

```css
.sbox {
  width: 297.297px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant-caps: normal;
  font-variant-ligatures: normal;
  font-variant-numeric: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: auto;
  position: relative;
  
}

.fb {
  background: url("../img/mag.png") no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/facebook.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <button value="1" class="tools" aria-label="Search" type="submit">
  <i class=fb></i>
</button>
    <input type="text" class="sbox" placeholder="Search " arial-label="Search" />
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you given the button any width or height...you can't see a bg image unless you do?

Comment: Im new to html/css as well but my suggestion would be not to use the "<button>" I would use <div id="my button"></div> and then build the button accordingly. https://codepen.io/hoyos/pen/vZrMbb

Comment: so look at the codepen i made in above comment and instead of background use  background-image: url("paper.gif");

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, I feel that you want to display an image in search box on the right. If so, please apply background image to class 'sbox' and the image position should be 'right 0'. The class 'sbox' will look as below:

```
.sbox {
  width: 297.297px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant-caps: normal;
  font-variant-ligatures: normal;
  font-variant-numeric: normal;
  font-weight:`enter code here` normal;
  cursor: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: -26px;
  background: url("../img/mag.png") no-repeat right 0;
}
```

And if you want the image (magnifying glass) to the button on the right, the code is as follows:

```
.fb {
background: url("../img/mag.png") no-repeat right 0;
width:15px;
height:14px;
display:inline-block;
float:right;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add background image to the button rather than using an i tag. i tags are used in html for alternate text moods. eg adding italics etc.

The reason they were adopted by font-awesome and bootstrap to show icons was mostly because they are inline-block by default and are efficient. But the way they do it is by adding a font file rather than using its background property

Here you should add the background to the button along with specifying a specific height and width to it.

```
<button value="1" class="tools fa" aria-label="Search" type="submit">
</button>

.fb {
  background: url("../img/mag.png") no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
 height:45px;
    width:50px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<i class=fb></i>` has no text content. Unless you specify some height and width in your CSS, your button will remain unaffected. Try adding this to `.fb`

```
.fb{
    height:50px; /*Assuming 50px because your background-size is 50px*/
    width:50px;
    display:block; /*Because height won't take effect on 'inline' elements*/
}
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I am trying to build a search box like facebook with a button on the right and a search icon on the top of the button... So what to do..?? The above code is not working for me.. :(

Comment: Why not add the image in the HTML itself within the button and add an `alt=Search`?